# How do recursive Rope Trick spells work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

You cast *rope trick* and then you cast it again from within the first extradimensional space. You wait within the second extradimensional space for the first *rope trick* to end and then for the second *rope trick* to end. Where do you drop out?

Do you drop out when the first *rope trick* ends or when the second one ends?

Do the rules for combining magical effects prevent the whole situation?

Comment: Related: [Question about being banished from rope trick](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171782/what-happens-when-a-banished-creature-would-return-to-an-extradimensional-space)

Comment: Related: [What happens to matryoshka Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147169/48827)

Answer (score 8):

### When the second one ends

The [*rope trick*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/rope-trick) spell description says:

> Anything inside the extradimensional space drops out when the spell ends.

That means that the portal leading to the second one would be shunted to the plane you were on when you cast *rope trick* the first time.  Since you, however, are not **in** the first space, you are not immediately shunted.

Answer (score 6):

### The spell just doesn't say enough

The spell says that *"Anything inside the extradimensional space drops out when the spell ends."* Are you inside the first space when it ends? Arguably not. So you don't fall out. So you drop out when the second *trick* ends. Where do you drop out *to*? Well, the spell is not specific about that, so you have some space for interpretation – I, personally can see it going two ways:

1. The DM does not hate you: you and everything else drop out onto the floor under the first casting of the rope trick, i.e. in your original location. This is just practical and it's the only relevant point in space...
2. The DM hates you and your weird spell bending shenanigans (a real possibility after recursively doing anything): Since the original spot where the second casting could drop you (in this interpretation, this means the first extradimensional space) no longer exists, you are hurled into timeless void appropriate to your campaign setting. Good luck in there!

Note that this is all open to all kinds of interpretations, since the rules are just not that specific.

Final point considering combining spell effects: there are no overlapping spell effects, since the targets of the two castings are two completely distinct lenghts of rope in different time and space.

Comment: Does the rope and the opening to the second *Rope Trick* count as things? Would they then be "dropped out" of the first *Rope Trick* when it ends?

Comment: @RevenantBacon An interdimensional opening is not a thing, IMHO. A length of rope surely is, so assuming the rope does not vanish together with the extradimensional space (which the spell does _not_ specify, but it also does not say it does, so it probably doesn't), it would be dropped out.

Comment: Pretty sure that, being a noun, it is, in fact, a thing.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Well, sure, if you want to disect it like that. Let me be super clear then. An interdimensional opening is very probably not a physical object. I would argue that things that are not physical objects are somewhat unable to be "dropped out". The description even guarantees that there is nothing to be seen after you pull the rope up, leaving very little space left for claiming existence of anything physical (invisible things are usually specified – see e.g. _Arcane eye_).

Comment: The spell doesn't specify "only physical objects", rather, it states "*anything* inside". And drop is really only in there because most objects are affected by gravity. In this instance, the other portal wouldn't "drop" out because it wouldn't fall, but it would still be forced out of the space. Also, a direct quote from the spell: "an invisible entrance". An entrance is a thing, and it is specified as being invisible" the same as with *Arcane Eye*